# How to create json From foreach in php

Tags: php, json

Please help me create json from this code , example

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "DASH": "fff72f33-e946-5945-b198-b405a652e078",
            "DOGE": "600ea0a0-dff7-5bf5-8eb2-0b56c3ba5922",
            }]}
```

Here is the php code I want to create this type of json response from it

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init(); 
 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jobians.top/coinbase/accounts.php?api=N7696pIFgkF7vagl&key=AF3RO2AIrhuLpw40kyEUnZcc975dRfQq", 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, 
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET" 
    )); 
$response = curl_exec($curl); 
 
curl_close($curl); 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json2 = json_decode($response, true);

$id_array = array_map(function($el) { return $el['id']; }, $json2['data']);
foreach ($json2['data'] as $el) {

echo "{$el['balance']['currency']}: {$el['id']}\n";

 }
?>
```

Please help me create json from this code

Please help me create json from this code

Comment: you need to create an array first from your response data inside the foreach loop and then when the array is filled with all the values you need you can use json_encode to create the output

Comment: Please how can I do it

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to add these lines to an object/array as data, then print the data as a json encoded string.

```
$outputObject = [];
foreach ($json2['data'] as $el) {
    $outputObject[$el['id']] = $el['balance']['currency'];
}
echo json_encode( $outputObject );
```

also, the output you are printing seems to be invalid JSON. you didn't give a great example of the output structure you expect, so I took liberties and guessed.

Comment: It working thanks, but please how can I end the the script here https://i.ibb.co/C2QJPgd/IMG-20220802-181451-618.jpg

Comment: I want the script not to show currency that don't have id like "fff72f33-e946-5945-b198-b405a652e078" is it possible?

Comment: I want something like this if(currency==id) script should exclude it

Comment: I don't know it in php help me create it please

Comment: I have try on my own and it didn't work that is why I posted here, please help me out

Comment: Please can you give me example

Comment: I have tried please help me create it

Comment: You need money to create it?